# Cordova Tools for Visual Studio won't build

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I'm receiving some errors ,anyone knows how to fix? I'm using visual studio 2015.

npm WARN deprecated npmconf@0.1.16: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

npm WARN install:rimraf@2.2.0 ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\

[Error: The edge module has not been pre-compiled for node.js version v5.4.0. You must build a custom version of edge.node. Please refer to https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge for building instructions.]
1>  ***************************************

npm ERR! code 1
1>  ------ npm install failed. Exit code: 1
1>  ------ Package installation failed. Retrying...
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"5.4.0","npm":"3.3.12"})
1>  npm WARN deprecated npmconf@0.1.16: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

** I already tried to clear cordova chache!

[image]

Comment: Can you try targeting Cordova version 5.4.1 and see if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install node.js yourself and not through the Visual Studio setup wizard?  There are some issues with newer versions of node that cause problems.  You have to use a version of node prior to 4.0 (you appear to have 5.4)  Uninstall node and move back to a previous version of node.

Here is documentation on the issue:
https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/known-issues-ripple-cordova/#strongbuild-not-executing-when-using-cordova-with-nodejs-500-and-cordova-533-and-belowstrong